# Android dev time vs iPhone dev time

Tags: iphone, android, time

IF someone has to develop the same application for Android and iPhone, is it more difficult to develop in one platform than on the other? Does it take more time?

Lets think about the average app. Lists, text , buttons, fetch information from the internet.

Person has same experience on both platforms.

Thanks

Comment: Does said person have exactly the same level of experience with both platforms?

Comment: yes, person has the same level of experience on both, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this depends a lot on what you're already familiar with. If you're real sharp with Objective-C, Cocoa, and Mac development in general, you'll probably be able to construct an application very quickly. On the other hand, if you've done lots of Java development, Android will be fast. Both platforms have advantages and disadvantages in terms of development time.

Answer (score 2):

I would say iPhone development is faster from the get go, since XCode IDE offers easier environment for development than Eclipse, with the time faster is what you are more familiar with.

Comment: "XCode IDE offers easier environment for development than Eclipse" any example?

Comment: I have used both. Eclipse rocks!!! Only good thing with xcode is the performace tools, which is needed for c-base development. unncessary for eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

if you make simple application with all the built in features of xcode and IB, then it would be easier. if you wanna tweak the app and customize a lot, run animation, make the app attractive, then iPhone can be a real mess at the first time.
I switched from JME/Android to iPhone. Customization in iPhone take much more time than others.

Answer (score 1):

The developer community support should also be taken into consideration. I am Android developer and i can tell for sure that Android Developer support is very very good...

Answer (score 0):

Depends, if you already know Java or Objective-C then it shouldn't matter, but most people will have to "get-up-to-speed" on one or the other, or possibly both.

If you are getting up to speed on both, I'd save Android/Java will be quicker to learn and deploy. But there are plenty of people making iPhone/Objective-C apps for the first time too.

If you have experiance with a managed environment like VB6 or .NET you'll be more likely to feel athome with Java than Objective-C.

Disclaimer: I am a .NET developer with some Java experience. The only Objective-C I've delt with is reading it online.

Comment: If you decide to pick up Objective-C, I think you'll find its pretty straightforward, especially if you have a C background.